# Jquery: MultiFile Plugin failing on IE7

Tags: jquery, multifile-uploader

I'm using this plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ to create a mail attach system, but it is failing to execute on IE7.

Here's my code:

```
$(".attachFile").live("click",function(){
    var id ="#"+$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    $(id + ' #attach').MultiFile({
        onFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element){ 
        $("#"+id + ' .attach-list').append('<li>onFileAppend - '+value+'</li>') 
        var options = { 
            url:       '/setAttach',         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
            type:      'POST'        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        }; 

        // bind to the form's submit event 
        $("#"+id + ' #uploadForm').submit(function() {

           $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

           return false; 
        });
    }, 
    afterFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element){ 
     $("#"+id + ' #uploadForm').submit();
    }
});
});
```

This event is fired when user clicks hover a link to attach files. 
Any clues for what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple `id="attach"` and `id="uploadForm"`?

Comment: Hi Nick, yes, #attach it's my input file, and uploadForm it's my form

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to a bug in jQuery 1.7:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10570

The MultiFile plugin used:
$("input[type=file].multi").MultiFile();

Thus cause a permission denied bug in IE7.

Possible solution would be upgrade jQuery to 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

cmedeiros, I'm the developer of the plugin in question.
What do you expect to happen? And what do you see instead?

I know you said it fails to execute, but at which point?

Comment: Hi Diego, It didn't bind the plugin to my element, I load MultFile at the time I create my input in the DOM, but it didn't bind it to my element. It works fine on IE8, but not in IE7. Also, I tested your examples at IE7 and everything worked fine. I think it's something on my application, that it's not allowing MultiFile to be attached through jquery .live() method. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: In your code you say...
$(id + ' #attach').MultiFile({

Can you verify that $(id + ' #attach') exists at that point?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, first create the element in the DOM, then bind MultiFile to it, and in the end append it to the screen:

```
var e = $("<div id=\""+id+"\" class=\"inner-center compose hidden\">"+$("#form").html()+"</div>");

$('#attach',e).MultiFile({ ... ACTIONS ... });

$(".middle-center").append(e);
```

Worked very well.